# How can I debug or catch windows service exception

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, service, visual-studio-debugging

I'm analyzing my (retired)co-worker`s windows application source(C#)

When I click service start button in application, that service turned start, but 2-3 sec later it stopped. So, I checked log in Event viewer, and it has some problem.

The process terminated by

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.

So I try to find the reason, but I don`t know how can I do that.

At first, I tried to use Process debugger in Visual studio,

But I mentioned earlier, the process stopped within only 2-3 sec, So, It`s impossible...

How can I check error or debug service???

I have a whole source. Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make you Program.cs like

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
   #if DEBUG
        Service1 myService = new Service1();
        myService.OnDebug();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
   #else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
   #endif

    }
}
```

and your Service1.cs file should be like..

```
   public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void OnDebug()
{
    OnStart(null);
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // your code to do something
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
}
```

Now, based on the mode Switch "Debug/Release" from Visual Studio, your Program.cs file will get enabled/disabled. If it is in debug then debug section will be enabled and other will be commented/disable and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your web service code using below code.

static class Program
    {

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new DataTransfer() 
        };

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
           RunInteractive(ServicesToRun);

        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }

        //ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }


    static void RunInteractive(ServiceBase[] servicesToRun)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Services running in interactive mode.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
        {
            Console.Write("Starting {0}...", service.ServiceName);
            onStartMethod.Invoke(service, new object[] { new string[] { } });
            Console.Write("Started");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Press any key to stop the services and end the process...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();

        MethodInfo onStopMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStop",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
        {
            Console.Write("Stopping {0}...", service.ServiceName);
            onStopMethod.Invoke(service, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All services stopped.");
        // Keep the console alive for a second to allow the user to see the message.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the above code and it was working great... then today I am getting an exception {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."   Inner exception: {"The specified service does not exist as an installed service"} Service Service1 was not found on computer '.'.